# ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1) error when running outlook email creator

Tags: python, valueerror

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1) is the error im getting when i try to run python app.py in terminal. I am using visual studio code. Here is the code from when i ran the app.

```
> python app.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\7932\Downloads\OutlookEmailCreator-master\OutlookEmailCreator-master\app.py", line 247, in <module>
    account_creator = OutlookAccountCreator(use_proxy=True)
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\7932\Downloads\OutlookEmailCreator-master\OutlookEmailCreator-master\app.py", line 59, in __init__
    self.driver = self.__open_browser(use_proxy)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\7932\Downloads\OutlookEmailCreator-master\OutlookEmailCreator-master\app.py", line 231, in __open_browser
    auth, ip_port = random_proxy.split('@')
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

Can someone help me fix it? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to tell without access to the code, but the error message is suggesting that there is no '@' character present in the `random_proxy` string. Maybe try print out the value of `random_proxy` immediately before the split happens to investigate?